# Using subsonic with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, subsonic, t4

I am trying to use SubSonic 3.0.0.4 T4 templates in Visual Studio 2012 and I am getting an error when attempting to Run Custom Tool:

```
Running transformation: System.ArgumentException: URI formats are not supported.
at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength)
at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
at System.IO.FileInfo.Init(String fileName, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.FileInfo..ctor(String fileName)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingDEA67E4EB0C1122C647D57B24990E6ADC926293FAA416AB931D00586F4B18B19835EBCF363314E3900B217C8CCCCBA2FE49FB073A2A661FD3E6B140615356056.GeneratedTextTransformation.GetProjectPath()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingDEA67E4EB0C1122C647D57B24990E6ADC926293FAA416AB931D00586F4B18B19835EBCF363314E3900B217C8CCCCBA2FE49FB073A2A661FD3E6B140615356056.GeneratedTextTransformation.GetConfigPath()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingDEA67E4EB0C1122C647D57B24990E6ADC926293FAA416AB931D00586F4B18B19835EBCF363314E3900B217C8CCCCBA2FE49FB073A2A661FD3E6B140615356056.GeneratedTextTransformation.GetConnectionString(String connectionStringName)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingDEA67E4EB0C1122C647D57B24990E6ADC926293FAA416AB931D00586F4B18B19835EBCF363314E3900B217C8CCCCBA2FE49FB073A2A661FD3E6B140615356056.GeneratedTextTransformation.get_ConnectionString()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingDEA67E4EB0C1122C647D57B24990E6ADC926293FAA416AB931D00586F4B18B19835EBCF363314E3900B217C8CCCCBA2FE49FB073A2A661FD3E6B140615356056.GeneratedTextTransformation.GetReader(String sql)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingDEA67E4EB0C1122C647D57B24990E6ADC926293FAA416AB931D00586F4B18B19835EBCF363314E3900B217C8CCCCBA2FE49FB073A2A661FD3E6B140615356056.GeneratedTextTransformation.LoadTables()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingDEA67E4EB0C1122C647D57B24990E6ADC926293FAA416AB931D00586F4B18B19835EBCF363314E3900B217C8CCCCBA2FE49FB073A2A661FD3E6B140615356056.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()    C:\SourceControl\Web Projects\XXX\xxx\App_Code\DAL\Classes.tt   1   1   http://localhost/XXX/
```

Typically I have been using VS2010 with web apps and running them with the built in web server. This project is hosted on my local IIS instance (not sure it that's making a difference or not).

Any help would be appreciated.

Joe

Answer (score 0):

I'm running 2012 and have no problems generating SubSonic-code through Run Custom Tool so must be something related to your project's configuration. Error message suggests something with ProjectPath - most likely when the T4 code is trying to find and pick up the connection string.